# R histogram store the calculated bin values

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, histogram

I have a figure that has percentage on x-axis and position on y-axis. The dataframe is large (more than 2 million rows), so I group the points to 10k bins and plot the mean percentage of the bin. The code I use is below:

```
ggplot(data, aes(norm_location, percentage, colour = class)) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun = "mean", 
                   geom="point", 
                   bins = 10000) +
```

Because of the size of the data, it takes really long to run this code every time I need to change something related to the figure (title, axis names, colors etc.) Is there a way to store the values of the bins in a smaller data frame which has 10k rows, and use that instead of the big data? What would be a more efficient way to generate this plot?

Thank you!

Comment: Storing what makes up the *body of the plot* in an object might be enough: `p = ggplot(data, aes(norm_location, percentage, colour = class)) + stat_summary_bin(fun = "mean", geom = "point", bins = 1e4)`. Then customise according to your needs, e.g. `p + theme_classic()`.

Comment: It's still the same, takes really long to plot the figure.

Comment: You could do this using the base `hist` function - it returns an object including the midpoints of each bin and the corresponding count and density. You could apply it by `class` group, extract those necessary elements,  covert to data frame, and still use `ggplot` to plot it.

Comment: A possible improvement to @Friede’s suggestion (which I think is simple and potentially useful) is to wrap the  initial definition of `p` in a call to `force()`. `ggplot` calls use lazy evaluation, so the initial definition will only be evaluated when it’s needed, not when it is defined. Don’t forget, you’ll always have the long wait at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to summarize the data before plotting in order to get better speed. This sounds quite reasonable to me. Plus, if you are happy to use `data table`, you can benefit from its multi-threading feature.

```
#sample data
data= data.table(norm_location = 1:2000000, percentage= runif(2000000, min=0, max=1), class = sample(c('apple','pear','orange'), 2000000, replace=T))

#manully slice 10000 bins and binwidth, and then plot only points of each bin
data[, binwidth := (max(norm_location)-min(norm_location))/10000, by = class][, 
.(percentage=mean(percentage)), by=.((norm_location-min(norm_location))%/%binwidth, class, binwidth)][, 
          norm_location:= norm_location*binwidth, by=class]%>%
  ggplot(aes(norm_location, percentage, colour = class)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: This works! Thank you! Can you explain the code please?

Comment: @cookiemonster Great to know it solved your question. The key in data preparation is calculating the binwidth and bin. As you want 10000 bins, we calculate the binwidth by dividing the range (min to max) of 'norm_location' by 10000 (`(max(norm_location)-min(norm_location))/10000` grouped by 'class'). Then, norm_location relative to the min divided by binwidth with flooring tell us which bin it is in (`(norm_location-min(norm_location))%/%binwidth`), and we get mean percentage in each bin. At last, convert the norm_location values back using `norm_location *binwidth`.

Answer (score 0):

You could sub-sample your data for the customization part, and reuse all dataset when everything is good for you :

```
set.seed(42)
data %>% 
  dplyr::slice_sample(n = 10000) %>% # or how many you want
  ggplot(aes(norm_location, percentage, colour = class)) +
    stat_summary_bin(fun = "mean", geom = "point", bins = 10000)
```

This will reduce the computational cost/time will keeping a similar aspect.